# how does the js command run in source codes?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc, javascript, ethereumjs

I just want to be clear how dose the js command run. I trace the code when I type `admin.peers` in `geth console`. Then I found that it runs in jsre.go:

```
// Evaluate executes code and pretty prints the result to the specified output
// stream.
func (self *JSRE) Evaluate(code string, w io.Writer) error {
    var fail error

    self.Do(func(vm *otto.Otto) {
        val, err := vm.Run(code)
        if err != nil {
            prettyError(vm, err, w)
        } else {
            prettyPrint(vm, val, w)
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(w)
    })
    return fail
}
```

may be val, err := vm.Run(code) could get the result of the command. But how does the otto JavaScript parser and interpreter connect the exact ethereum code ? how does the `vm.Run(code)` get the result? thank you.